# How can I call a function from another class which have driver?

Tags: java, selenium

I can't call a function from another class, which contain driver Chrome.

I try to call the function, but I get an error.

BaseTest class - this contain drive Chrome from all classes.

```
public class Waiters extends BaseTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Waiters(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("auth-user-name")));
    }
```

The BaseTest containt this function, with ChromeDriver, but this is ok, because I use that in more classes, and it's working ok.

```
public class BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver;

    protected WebDriver initiliazeDriver() {
        return driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

This is the class where I want to call the function from Waiters:

```
public class LoginPageDB extends BaseTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPageDB(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    private Waiters waiters = new Waiters(null);

public void loginDbWithValidCredentialsDeutsch(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException{
        openLoginDbPage();
        waiters.waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB(); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
        typeUserNameDB(username);
        typePasswordDB(password);
        pressLoginButtonDB();
        verifyIfTheLoginWasSuccessDB();
    }
```

In the LoginPageDB, I want to call the function waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB() from Waiters class.

Comment: If you get an error, please share it.

Comment: It's very general error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because you are passing a WebDriver as `null` in `LoginPageDB` class and then it is used in this line

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);
```

when you do the call:

```
waiters.waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB();
```

Past a real instance of WebDriver class and you won't get the NullPointerException

Comment: yep..I tried with "driver", what is normal, but same error. 
How I modified WebDriver: http://prntscr.com/p98i3u
List with error: http://prntscr.com/p98ifg

Comment: If the ```WebDriver``` is passed into ```LoginPageDB``` by constructor and it still fails you should check where are you getting the driver from and see if it is a valid WebDriver

Comment: the `WebDriver` is valid. It is from `BaseTest` class. Look up, I uploaded this class here. And this is ok, because this class I used for more classes until now, and all it's good with it. The problem is, if I declare correct the `Waiters` class in `Login `class...I think..

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is in the `Waiters` class. This look is the problem: ` WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);`, but I don't know what is the problem with this. @Pablo

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your implementation

First you have a private `Webdriver` field named `driver` in your `Waiters` class and a public Webdriver field also named driver in your `BaseTest` class. Instead you should remove the driver field from your Waiters class and define it as a protected field in your BaseTest class.

In the Waiters constructor use `super(new ChromeDriver())` instead of `this.driver = driver`. This way the base instance will be properly initialized.

Since the driver field is protected it will be visible to any child instance so a Waiters instance can access it.

The two classes should then look like the following:

```
public class Waiters extends BaseTest {

    public Waiters() {
        super(new ChromeDriver());
    }

    public void waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("auth-user-name")));
    }
}
```

And the BaseTest class:

```
public class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BaseTest(Webdriver driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
    }

    protected WebDriver initiliazeDriver() {
        return driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

In your LoginPageDB class, instanciate the Waiters class correctly for example instead of

```
private Waiters waiters = new Waiters(null);
```

write for example:

```
private Waiters waiter = new Waiters();
```

You should not have that NPE anymore and your code should work correctly

If you want to use the initializeDriver method instead of a parameterized constructor, add an equivalent of a default constructor in the BaseTest class so it looks like:

```
 public class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BaseTest() {
    }

    protected WebDriver initiliazeDriver() {
        return driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

And in your Waiters class add a non parameterized constructor that will call the initializeDriver method of the base class:

```
    public class Waiters extends BaseTest {

       public Waiters() {
          initializeDriver();
       }

       public void waitToDisplayUsernameLabelDB() {
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("auth-user-name")));
       }
   }
```

And in this case you can use the following Waiters instanciation successfully in your LoginPageDB (notice that no parameter uis given to the constructor here)

```
private Waiters waiters = new Waiters();
```

Comment: `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor` - I received that

Comment: @Gabril EL right, a simple run will not allow the test framework to know how to pass arguments to the constructor, I just updated the code snippets